# UserWarning: libxml2 not available

Tags: plone, libxml2

At the end of a migration of my zope2.9.6 from a gentoo distribution to a cento5 one in which i compiled a specific python version (python-2.4.6) used for running zope when i run
/opt/instances/zope-2.9.6/bin/runzope

i got the following warning

/opt/instances/zope-2.9.6/Products/Marshall/handlers/**init**.py:38: UserWarning: libxml2 not available. Unable to register libxml2 based marshallers
  warnings.warn('libxml2 not available. Unable to register libxml2 based ' \

how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a warning, not an error. In fact, in later versions of Plone, it is downgraded to an "info" message.

Unless you need to use Marshall for XML-based import or export of Plone data you can — and should — ignore this message.

Marshall is the only Plone component (in later versions of Plone, it is an optional add-on) which uses the old python-libxml libraries. And, it only uses it for XML import / export. The only popular use I know that folks are making of these components is for transmogrifier export import pipelines. Unless you're doing something like that, just be reassured that this is no problem whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

First you should install these system packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev python-lxml python-libxml2
```

and then you'll need to recompile your python in order to let it be aware of new packages.
If you are using a buildout you can also try this:

```
[buildout]
parts +=
    ...
    lxml
eggs +=
    ...
    lxml == 2.1.2

[lxml]
recipe=plone.recipe.lxml
egg = lxml == 2.1.2
```

Comment: These are the steps I followed:

Comment: These are the steps I followed:
yum install libxml2 libxml2-devel libxml2-python python-lxml
cd /root/tmp/Python-2.4.6
./configure --prefix=/opt/python-2.4.6
make
make install

I've also installed other python libraries for my zope installation and the 
/opt/instances/zope-2.9.6/bin/runzope
getting the same warning 
/opt/instances/zope-2.9.6/Products/Marshall/handlers/__init__.py:38: UserWarning: libxml2 not available. Unable to register libxml2 based marshallers
  warnings.warn('libxml2 not available. Unable to register libxml2 based ' \